# using .vim plugins with pathogen

Tags: vim

I want to use lustyjuggler and lustyExplorer. They are vim plugins but I want to us pathogen to manage them. Normally I unzip vim plugins and the whole folder structure goes into `~/.vim/bundle/`. But with lustyJuggler and lustyExplorer they come as .vim files. How do I get these to work with pathogen?

Comment: LustyExplorer includes LustyJuggler's functionnality. I don't think you need both.

Comment: No, LustyExplorer and LustyJuggler are separate plugins, though they do share some common code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the folders `~/.vim/bundle/lustyJuggler/plugin` and `~/.vim/bundle/lustyExplorer/plugin` and place the .vim files in there

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vim-scripts mirrors:

https://github.com/vim-scripts/LustyJuggler
https://github.com/vim-scripts/LustyExplorer

Or you can create your own filestructure, just make the plugin folder manually, i.e.

```
~/.vim/bundle/lustyX/plugin/whatever.vim
```